# Is it possible to make double space appear as tabs?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm working in a project that uses the standard javascript syntax. It's nice, but it uses spaces for indentation. Is there some way to make double spaces work as tabs, with the ability to set tab-space etc?

Comment: Does your `tab` key not work?  Perhaps you can Search/Replace `space space` -> `tab`. Sublime text (and I suspect most code editors) has a setting that lets you *use* the `tab` key, but have it insert a (pre specified number of) spaces instead. In other words, with the setting, the editor will *not* insert the `\t` marker, indicating a tab character, but instead insert the specified number of `space` characters.  Which is the opposite of what you want. If this setting is off, then a `tab` key will enter a `tab` character, and a `space` key will enter a space character - is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible. Spaces and tabs are different by nature and they're also used differently in different projects. Some projects prefer to maintain the standard of *only* spaces, or tab and spaces or only tabs.

What you're asking is basically: is it possible to show all letters A as a letter O?

However, something that might help for your case is automatic indentation / code beautifier. Most code editors have this feature and it basically indents your code based on a standard (which you most of the time can customize).

If you're using PHP Storm for example, the shortcut [ctrl + alt + L](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/10.0/reformatting-source-code.html) will indent and beautify your code. On the ATOM editor you can install a [package](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify) to add that feature.

Keep in mind that messing about with indentation might cause conflicts with git if you're part of a team. And, if you're part of a team it's always better to keep their standards anyway.

As a final note, spaces vs tabs is a religious war. Try to keep your team's or library standard is a good recommendation most of the time.